# What does "arguable" mean here?

Tags: word-usage

"This made the television advertising of mass consumer products relatively straightforward ― not to say easy ― whereas today it is necessary for advertisers to build up coverage of their target markets over time, by advertising on a host of channels with separate audiences.
Still, it is **arguable** that advertisers worry rather too much about this problem, as advertising in other media has always been fragmented. Moreover, advertisers gain considerable benefits from the price competition between the numerous broadcasting stations."

Q. What does "it is **arguable**" mean here? "it is **controversial** and **doubtful**" or "it is **almost certain**"?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! We expect people to do a little research before asking a question. In this case, you could look up the word **arguable** in a good dictionary, for example this one: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arguable If you still have concerns, please edit your question to add details of your research and to explain what exactly is still unclear.

Comment: It seems that you have done your research, but haven't included it in your question. We ask for these details because we can answer your question more accurately if we know exactly why it's not clear to you. In particular, I have never seen a definition that says it means "it is almost certain". Just edit your question to add links to the dictionary definitions, or copy them in if you are not using an online dictionary,  and explain that you are confused because the dictionary definitions offer two opposite meanings.

Comment: A useful resource is this entry https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/able_2 on the suffix -able which may help you with many similar words in future.

Comment: The whole point of including references to your research is that you don't need to explain so much in a foreign language: the links to references give us most of the information that we need to understand your question. And yes, I do know how hard it is to explain problems in a foreign language: I have lived outside the UK for the past 17 years.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> This made the television advertising of mass consumer products relatively straightforward ― not to say easy ― **whereas today** it is necessary for advertisers to build up coverage of their target markets over time, by advertising on a host of channels with separate audiences. **Still**, it is **arguable** that advertisers **worry rather too much** about this problem, as advertising in other media has always been fragmented. **Moreover**, advertisers **gain considerable benefits**...."

Edit

> arguable
> /ˈɑːɡjʊəb(ə)l/
> adjective

> 1. able to be argued or asserted.
>    Similar:
>    tenable
>    defensible

> 2. open to disagreement; not obviously correct.

Google gives 2 almost opposite definitions for *arguable*, and hence we have to interpret based on the context of the passage.
From the keywords, we can interpret that *arguable* takes on the 1st definition, i.e., *tenable* or *defensible*, meaning advertisers worry too much.  The subsequent clause with 'Moreover' reinforces this point.

I would not go as far as taking *almost certain* as the definition.

Comment: I think that you may be trying to guess the meaning of the word from the context. That's not always a good idea: a dictionary is much more reliable. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arguable

Comment: @JavaLatte, as I stated in my answer, I had check Google Dictionary.   The 2 definitions are disparate, and hence we have to interpret from the passage.

Comment: If you refer to a dictionary entry, please provide a link to it, then we know exactly what you are referring to.  In this instance, if I google "google dictionary" then follow the link, I get a 404 error (Not found).

Comment: @mystery, I have edited my answer, incorporating further details.